David Tong, notes on General Relativity, pg. 25
I was studying GR using David Tong's notes, which I find very compelling and easy to read. The material is explained clearly to a fault, and I would recommend anyone picking up GR to at least skim through these notes to solidify some concepts.
However, on page 25, I am struggling to understand the expansion that is performed. Tong talks about "double expansion" (which I assume means double Taylor expansion), I did the first one, but I have trouble understanding how he does the 2nd. Specifically:
$$
T_{B} = t  \sqrt{1 - \frac{2 GM}{(r_{A} + \Delta r)c^2}} \approx t \sqrt{1 - \frac{2 GM}{r_{A}c^2} + \frac{2 GM \Delta r}{r_{A}^2c^2}} \approx t \sqrt{1 - \frac{2 GM}{r_{A}c^2}}  \left(1 + \frac{GM\Delta r}{r_{A}^2c^2}\right) = T_{A} \left(1 + \frac{GM \Delta r}{r_{A}^2c^2}\right)
$$
I am struggling to understand what the author does to arrive from the first to the second "roughly equal" sign.

I was puzzled enough to look at what the notes actually say.  You have the quote  right though.
I think he starts from
$$
\sqrt{a+x}= {\sqrt a}\sqrt{1+ \frac x a}\\
\approx \sqrt{a}\left(1+ \frac 12 \frac  xa\right).
$$
But now $a\approx 1$, so he forgets the $a$ in $x/a$ to get
$$
\sqrt{a+x}\approx \sqrt{a}\left(1+ \frac x 2\right).
$$

Makes sense. Thanks a lot!
